# Mocha Not Loading Test In Sub Folders

Tags: mocha.js

I have this command in my package.json:

```
NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:$PWD/frontend mocha --compilers js:babel-register --require ./frontend/test/helpers.js --recursive frontend/test/**/*.js
```

I can have my files under frontend/test/public/file1.js and frontend/test/private/file2.js working. But when I create sub folders such as frontend/test/public/**food**/food_test.js or frontend/test/private/**panel**/panel_test.js, mocha doesn't run them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is to remove `**/*.js`. The command is like below:

```
NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:$PWD/frontend mocha --compilers js:babel-register --require ./frontend/test/helpers.js --recursive frontend/test
```

Comment: ...respectively `"recursive": true` in [.mocharc](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/example/config/.mocharc.yml)